# Painting location identification

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this

I received two framed pieces of art and wonder if they are real places and where.  They could very well be fictional and may or may not be copies of famous works.  They are just furniture store art, and I don't see an artist's signature.  There were no identifying stickers, labels or description accompanying them. Unfortunately, an iPhone is the only camera that I own.

Hopefully someone can either recognize the area or if they are copies of famous works then we should be able to find out the location.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Google didn't turn up any famous originals for these. The best I found was a  web site in Japan selling exactly the first item, described only as 'Italian city scene'. Assuming these are being sold around d the world they're probably being painted in volume in a workshop in the Far East by a team of painters (I wouldn't call them artists).

Comment: The triple copper dome in the first scene is pretty distinctive, but I'm having trouble concretely identifying it as a specific building. The closest I got was it possibly being the west register house with edinburgh castle behind. Most likely these are both generic "italian city" scenes of no particular location.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yeah I figured they were mass produced, just wondering if they are based on something.  Possible but, I think, not plausible, there are Asian people/companies just producing "townscapes" with no reference.  If I were to produce a "painting", I would probably have a reference, place, photo, another painting etc. Maybe not, hence my question.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I spent some time in the art trade in Britain a few years ago. Mass-produced 'original' oil paintings were freely available at the trade shows for just a few pounds each, all from companies based in Taiwan, Vietnam, Malaysia, etc. This is not only possible, but highly likely.

Comment: @Airsick I think the "not plausible" bit is the proposition that such paintings are mass produced without an actual scene to work from, or at least a famous image of an imaginary scene, not that such mass productions exist.

Comment: @phoog I agree that the workshops are working from a template, but that template need only be an image painted by an artist who could be working from imagination. There's no need for the template images to have any basis in reality.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are plenty of originals by famous period artists which do not match "reality", as features such as buildings, trees and orientations were commonly moved around or left out to aid the composition and balance of the painting.  Watching shows such as Time Team gives you a good idea of just how inaccurate paintings can be.

Answer (score 2):

The locations are an amalgam of Italian architecture from various and doesn't exist as such in real life. I wish I had a more detailed response but that's all there is to it.